# A question about elementary combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Without computing directly, how to show that $\dfrac{\binom{100}{50}}{2^{100}}<0.1$ easily?

Comment: Your question is equivalent to [$\prod_{i=1}^{50} \frac {2i-1}{2i} < \frac {1}{10}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274753/solve-this-inequality-prod-i-150-frac-2i-12i-frac-110/274769#274769).

Answer (score 2):

You may use the estimate

$$\frac{1}{2^{2 n}} \binom{2 n}{n} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  Then

$$\frac{\binom{100}{50}}{2^{100}} \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{50 \pi}} < 0.1$$

This is derived using Stirling's Approximation.  The (relative) error in the approximation is $1/(8 n)$, or about 1 part in 400 at $n=50$.